# ruby on rails and mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

is there a library like mongoid for rails 2.1 ?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

See: [Mongo Mapper](http://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Mongoid version 1.x work with Rails 2.x? It says so on the [homepage](http://mongoid.org/)...

Answer (score 0):

None of these libs are working with my project :

rake routes outputs :
...

can't activate activesupport (= 2.3.8, runtime) for [], already activated activesupport-2.1.2 for ["rails-2.1.2"]
...